# Sorting a two dimensional array on the basis of one row data

Tags: java, arrays

I am not sure if the title rightly suggests what I am trying to ask. Let's say  I have a two dimensional int array as below:

```
int[][] x={{1,7,6},{2,4,8}};
```

Now I want to sort the first row in ascending order and the data in the 2nd row must be in the same column after the sorting, i.e., after sorting, the array should be like this:

```
x={{1,6,7},{2,8,4}}
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Will you only have two rows of data? Or could you have N rows? If N rows, you could pull the row you're sorting on into a list of pairs of values to original indexes, sort on values, then for each row make a new array, pull original values by the indexes and replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by implementing your own sort routine but a better approach would be to refactor.

Try encapsulating the data as an array of pairs of numbers, each pair wrapped in its own object. You can then sort on the first value and access either value.

```
class Pair<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Pair<T>> {
  final T a;
  final T b;

  public Pair ( T a, T b ) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Pair<T> o) {
    // Comparison on 'a' only.
    return a.compareTo(o.a);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString () {
    return "{" + a + "," + b + "}";
  }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
  Pair[] pairs = {
    new Pair(1,2),
    new Pair(7,4),
    new Pair(6,8),
  };
  System.out.println("Before: "+Arrays.toString(pairs));
  Arrays.sort(pairs);
  System.out.println("After: "+Arrays.toString(pairs));
}
```

prints

```
Before: [{1,2}, {7,4}, {6,8}]
After: [{1,2}, {6,8}, {7,4}]
```

Comment: this aproche is not good, because you have to crate many unneeded objects. And add complecity to solution by creating new class.

Comment: @AleksanderGralak - the alternative is to write your own sort algorithm. Your choice.

Comment: Nope. You can use my solution. It is in one of the answers. No new classes, no new objects. Sorry one new object: comparator. And you still have array efficiency.

Comment: Your solution is good for sorting different object types. Therefore if efficiency is not a concern (usually it is not), then generic solution will be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done by implementing your own sorting algorithm and move values in second row.

You might have an array of Obejcts. Each object will hold to values. Then implement your custom comparator and use sort function.

I have one more idea: reorder you array (if you can do so). Then keep pairs in one int[] table. And the outer table is a conatiner for int tables:

```
int [][] a = {{2,5},{1,4},{3,6}};
Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator<int[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(int[] p_o1, int[] p_o2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(p_o1[0]).compareTo(p_o2[0]);
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Your idea was my first one. But then I thought that there must be a way to do it without so much coding.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way would be to create a `Pair` object that holds the pairs, and sort the collection of Pairs with a custom comparator that only compares the first item of a Pair.

You can always transform your Pairs back to a 2D array if required.

That's probably not the most efficient way but should be good enough for most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

In case all of the first row's elements are unique and non-null, you can, before sorting, populate a map where first-row elements point to their second-row counterparts. After sorting the first row, you can then use the map to look up the first (sorted) row's corresponding elements of the second row.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically doing a `Map`, why don't you use an `Map` implementation to assist you?

`TreeMap` implements `SortedMap`, so an easy solution would be placing all your mapped values inside it:

```
SortedMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
map.put(1, 2);
map.put(7, 4);
map.put(6, 8);

// You can iterate over map now, it'll be already sorted
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry: map.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
}

// This is not really necessary
Integer[][] x = {map.keySet().toArray(new Integer[0]), map.values().toArray(new Integer[0])};

// If you have Apache Commons you can:
int[][] y = {ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(map.keySet().toArray(new Integer[0])), ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(map.values().toArray(new Integer[0]))};
```

Answer (score 0):

I copy pasted qSort from  http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort and with a little modification

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[][] x = { { 1, 7, 6 }, { 2, 4, 8 } };
        qsort(x[0], x[1], 0, x[0].length - 1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(x));
    }

    static void qsort(int[] x0, int[] x1, int left, int right) {
        int index = partition(x0, x1, left, right);
        if (left < index - 1)
            qsort(x0, x1, left, index - 1);
        if (index < right)
            qsort(x0, x1, index, right);
    }

    static int partition(int[] x0, int[] x1, int left, int right) {
        int i = left, j = right;
        int tmp;
        int pivot = x0[(left + right) / 2];
        while (i <= j) {
            while (x0[i] < pivot)
                i++;
            while (x0[j] > pivot)
                j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                tmp = x0[i];
                x0[i] = x0[j];
                x0[j] = tmp;

                // swap x1 too
                tmp = x1[i];
                x1[i] = x1[j];
                x1[j] = tmp;

                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

this program prints

```
[[1, 6, 7], [2, 8, 4]]
```

This may seem long, but usually for algorithms efficiency is critical, and this solution seems to be the fastest